# Firebase Database in SQL

Tags: sql, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know if it is possible to use Firebase as a SQL database. I have trouble with relations in NoSQL.

For example: a user belongs to a team, and a team has users.

Comment: IMO you should do it manually. Export your Firebase DB to JSON then write some code to import it to your SQL DB using your design relations.

Comment: The NoSQL database in Firebase is designed to be retrieved and used as is. If most of your data is relational, use a relational database. However, if you have very few relations, like the one you've mentioned, you would have to have a users node and a teams node in which each user has a node for the team(s) and each team has a node for the users. You must update both the teams node as well as the users node whenever there is a change.

Comment: If you want to use a SQL database, use a SQL database. There are plenty of good options for that. If you want to use Firebase, learn about NoSQL. Recommended for that: [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Answer (score 19):

It is not possible to use Firebase in this way. Firebase is a real-time object store. It is not a SQL database and is not intended to be a replacement for one. It completely lacks mechanisms such as JOINs, WHERE query filters, foreign keys, and other tools relational databases all provide. That doesn't mean it isn't a valuable tool. But any attempt to treat it "like" a SQL replacement is going to fail. That's not its purpose.

Comment: there is a foreign key like function available -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtoxRg-kbt0&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s

Comment: Sorry, no it doesn't. Validation rules can access keys in multiple locations, but those are strictly server-side and are NOT foreign keys. This isn't criticism of the product. It's an acknowledgment that trying to build apps with it using these SQL-realm assumptions is not effective. Firebase is different. It needs to be used the way it was designed to get all of its benefits.

Comment: to quote from video - "you can create foreign key like constructs" https://youtu.be/rtoxRg-kbt0?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&t=415 - I'm going to steer away from firebase and roll a sqlite db / just have the head of keeping it in sync.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Firebase includes 'WHERE' query filters. Some of the basic examples appear to use it.

Comment: This post is from 2017. Firebase has grown a lot since then, and Firebase Cloud Firestore does have a lot of this functionality now (Realtime Database still does not).

Answer (score 8):

I think what you need is [supabase](https://supabase.io/).

It uses an **Open Source** **Postgres Database** and they're trying to be a firebase alternative.

It's backed by YCombinator but is still in beta as of Feb, 2021.

Comment: Is it production ready? Does any major projects use it?

Comment: No major issues but this isn't ready for major projects. Check the community out. See what they're saying about a full release.