# Import live SQL Server Data to Firebase?

Tags: sql-server, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sql-server-express

I know that SQL is a relational database and Firebase is a NoSQL database (non relational) and i am trying to find out if there is any existing middleware that would allow Firebase to import SQL data (read only, maybe using a JSON dump of some sort?).

I have a developer familiar with Firebase in building web apps (dashboards) and was exploring this possibility as he is not very familiar with SQL db's.

Is this a stupid idea or should we just find a developer to do the DB work for us?

saw this thread: [Firebase Database in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222347/firebase-database-in-sql)

and also this plugin: https://zapier.com/zapbook/firebase/sql-server/
But not sure if this is what i need done

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Firebase fully supports importing of JSON formatted data. So if you get the data you have into a JSON structure your are set. Exporting JSON from SQL varies wildly from platform to platform so there's not going to be a single solution. You should also consider how you are going to work with that data in that going from SQL to NoSQL, things like joins have to be fashioned differently which may alter how you want to structure your Firebase. That being said stack overflow is really for code specific questions so this is a bit off topic.

Comment: any suggestions on where i could post this as more of a discussion?

Comment: I would check out the Firebase google group as it's a bit more free-form. Quite honestly though, there's a lot of back-end stuff involved with your question and without specifics, any answer would be a total guess. You should probably have your Firebase developer in the loop - getting data out of SQL (in general) is essentially a Export To Flat File (ascii, .txt etc) so that parts easy. Data modeling is the challenge.

Comment: Thanks Jay, i appreciate the suggestions!