# How apply sql query to Firebase in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.ios

I need get return data from Firebase. In Sql query it would be like this:

```
Select * from * Group By field1, field2 HAVING count(*)=1
```

How to apply above to FireBase in Xamarin Android. So I have node "chats", here I want retrieve record only not repeated on field "user_email":

```
chats
 |-...
   |---date_and_time:
   |---user_email:
 |-...
   |---date_and_time:
   |---user_email:
 ...
```

at this moment I get whole data from "chat", here code:

```
public List<MessageContent> listOfContacts = new List<MessageContent>();
FirebaseClient firebase;
...
firebase = new FirebaseClient(GetString(Resource.String.database_name));
...
var firebaseContacts = await firebase.Child("chats")
                                                 .OnceAsync<MessageContent>();
            foreach (var item in firebaseContacts)
                listOfContacts.Add(item.Object);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Database in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222347/firebase-database-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase's realtime database is a NoSQL database. Trying to directly map a SQL query to it is going to give you a rough time. I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

In NoSQL databases you typically get more complex write operations and in return get more performant/scalable read operations. So in your case, that could mean that you actually store a list of the records that you're trying to query and update that list with every write.

Some previous questions that deal with similar scenarios can be found in [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+aggregate).